# Using custom model binder on a model that contains dynamic entries(list)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my main class which is going to be my view `model`:

```
public class Entries
{   
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Items> items { get; set; }
}
```

it contains a varying number of

```
public class Items
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public int ownerID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string deleted { get; set; }
}
```

So it can be 0~100 when it comes to Index size depending on the user input.

`id` will be the main identifier of the row while `ownerID` is for foreign key purposes.

The form will be posted to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Entries entry)
{
```

Which is pretty simple.

My problem is that, I need to render the `ObjectID` through the use of hiddenfor helper since I need to show the list and for POST purposes. After POST submit, It won't bind to the `ObjectID` property because it was converted to `string`. I need to use `ObjectID.Parse(string)` to convert it back.

One solution that I can think of is by using temporary property that will hold the `ObjectID` as string and just convert it later on.

I want to solve this through the use of `ModelBinder` and here is what I have so far:

```
public class ObjBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                      ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string id = request.Form.Get("id");
        string firstname = request.Form.Get("firstname");
        string lastname = request.Form.Get("lastname");          
        string address = request.Form.Get("address");

        List<Items> temp = new List<Items>();

    //how do i add them to the list?
    // request.Form.Get("items[0].id") but I need to know the row count

        return new Entries
        {
            id = id,
            name = name,
            lastname = lastname,                    
            address = address,
            items = temp

        };
}
```

Is it possible to know the row count of my `items[]` so I can just loop through it?

Comment: You cannot bind to a complex object using `HiddenFor()` (look at the html your generating - its `value="yourAssembly.ObjectId"` and a custom ModelBinder wont help at all (unless you have overridden the `.ToString()` method of `ObjectId`). Why not just use a view model or generate hidden inputs for each property of `ObjectId`?

Comment: I did something like `return new Residents
            {
                id = ObjectId.Parse(id),
                name = name,
                address = address,
          
            };`  on my model binder before and that `id` is from `HiddenFor`. The value that I get from the auto generated HTML hidden for is the `ObjectID` value in form of string.

Comment: Everything in html is a string. What is the `value` attribute that your generating?

Comment: I get `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The id field is required." id="items_0__id" name="items[0].id" type="hidden" value="5781c07bb74c8325f49a4329" />`, Should I use a temporary property and just convert it from there?

Comment: You have not shown your model for `ObjectId`, but your must have overriden the `.ToString()` method to return (I assume) the ID property of `ObjectId`. Since you only want the ID property, then just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.items[i].id.ID)` (assuming the property is name `ID`)

Comment: Oh, `ObjectID` is a struct property from `MongoDB.Bson`. So that's the ID itself. I need to run `ObjectID.Parse(string)` to convert my value from `HiddenFor`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116911/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-carlos-miguel-colanta).